# Faking Microsoft Outlook Voting Button responses

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, spoofing

As we occasionally get company wide voting options of a variety of seriousness, it would be nice to customize replies to these messages.

From what I can ascertain, the main response is a change in the subject line
e.g. [Response value]:[Original subject], however sending an email with this response is not enough.

I suspect you would have to do it using a completely empty body text, but I do not have the tools to investigate this further.

Does anyone know how to spoof these messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can access VotingOptions and VotingResponse properties via macros and set them to generate an email with the appropriate response format but whether this will help depends on what sort of customised reply are you thinking of.

Comment: will give that a go